# Looking for late 70s short story anthology, we'd call it YA now. May have included Leiber's "A Pail of Air"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia

Read this in the school library - all the stories were very dysotopian.  One involved a character named 'Emelen' who by the end of the story discovers they are just one of many discarded clones (MLN).  Another told the story of a boy and his science fair project involving cereal where he determined that the ruling government (which was a corporation who owned all of the US) was adding a drug to dumb down the populace.

Comment: I remember "A Pail of Air", cool story.  Googling found someone in a similar situation to you, and someone commented "anthology w/a lurid purple and orange cover, called “Tomorrow’s Children”." http://chawedrosin.wordpress.com/2007/05/23/a-pail-of-air-by-fritz-lieber/

Answer (score 6):

This is a long shot, but could it be *The Other Side of Tomorrow*, edited by Roger Elwood. For some reason I associate the name Emelen with this anthology. I thought I had a copy but after a brief search I can't find it, and a quick Google doesn't help much. The only thing is that I don't remember "A Pail of Air" being in the book.

Comment: ISFDB to the rescue: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?44950 - however A Pail Of Air is not in this anthology, nor is any story that looks like it would contain "Emelen".

Comment: See http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Pr53U0JtGCcC&q=emelen so it's the story The Others by J. Hunter Holly. However this is obviously a red herring.

Comment: Not sure why you think it's a red herring. Since The Others and the cereal story (obviously A Bowl Of Biskies by Raymond F. Jones) are both in that anthology, it's clearly the right one; OP did only say that A Pail Of Air "may" have been in it.

Comment: Ah, yes. In fact http://raymondfjones.tripod.com/farthest.htm mentions the story A Bowl of Biskies and it does fit with the OP's description. I appear to have got the right book, if more by luck than judgement :-)

Comment: Thank you all - has to be The Other Side of Tomorrow!  The Speeders was also one of the stories.  Many, many thanks!  Now, to somehow track down a copy.

Comment: @TimothyJaxon - http://www.alibris.com/The-Other-Side-of-Tomorrow-Original-Science-Fiction-Stories-about-Young-People-of-the-Future-Roger-Elwood/book/4916084?matches=19